# Bootstrap modal window does not close

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap modal in a react application . I have a requirement that the modal window should not close when clicking on modal backdrop . For this I am using

```
$(".modal").modal("backdrop":"static");
```

which works perfectly fine . But in the next scenario , I want the same modal to close on clicking on backdrop using the following code.

```
$(".modal").modal("backdrop":true);
```

But this is not working .

I tried this too

```
$('#modal').modal('hide');
```

Please provide a feasible solution for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close bootstrap modal you can pass 'hide' as option to modal method as follow

```
$('#modal').modal('hide');
```

Bootstrap also provide events that you can hook into modal functionality, like if you want to fire a event when the modal has finished being hidden from the user you can use **hidden.bs.modal** event you can read more about modal methods and events here in [***Documentation***](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an object to the `modal` function, you can pass [these](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options) properties

For closing the modal, you should use `$(".modal").modal("hide")` [link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modalhide)

Comment: this is the only snippet